# How to get ids of duplicate names in contact

Tags: apex, account, contact, duplicate-management

I have an account record named with sForceTest1.

The sForceTest1 account have **dup1,dup2,dup3,dup1,dup2 and dup3** contacts, By seeing those contacts, you can known that sForceTest1 have duplicate contact records.

So far I tried with the following snippet.

```
Public class Example11 {
    Public List<Account> accs {set;get;}
    Public Set<String> setresult {set;get;}
    Public List<Id> conids {set;get;}

    Public void main(){
        setresult = new Set<String>();
        conIds = new List<Id>();
        accs = [select id,name,(select id,lastname,AccountId from contacts) from Account where id='0012800001EcUSl'];
        for(Account aa : accs) {
            for(Contact cc: aa.contacts) {
                setresult.add(cc.lastname);
                conids.add(cc.id);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I think above code is not useful to get the ids. By using this code I can get the names where as i couldn't get the ids of those records.

How can I get the ids of these duplicates records?

Comment: dup1,dup2,dup3,dup1,dup2 and dup3 contacts you mean they have lastName equals  dup1,dup2,dup3,dup1,dup2 and dup3 ?

Comment: I think that this code is supposed to work. Your ids are supposed to be in the `conids` list. Why are you saying that this doesn't work? Is this list empty?

Comment: @beham, yes. Those were created with lastname. like `LastName = dup1`

Comment: @MartinLezer, This code will give all the ids including duplicate names also. Actually i need ids of duplicate records.

Comment: Are you trying to get last name wise duplicate ids? like map of name and duplicate ids?

Comment: @blackPerl, I am trying to get last name wise duplicates ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will work perfectly with slight modification. The below code checks if set contains contact `lastname`. If its true the current contact is a duplicate. So you can add it to `conids`. Else add `lastname` to the set. Now `conids` will have all duplicate contact ids of particular account.

```
Public class Example11 {
    Public List<Account> accs {set;get;}
    Public Set<String> setresult {set;get;}
    Public List<Id> conids {set;get;}

    Public void main(){
        setresult = new Set<String>();
        conIds = new List<Id>();
        accs = [SELECT id, name, 
                       (SELECT id, lastname, AccountId 
                        FROM contacts) 
                FROM Account 
                WHERE id = '0012800001EcUSl'];
        for(Account aa : accs) {
            for(Contact cc: aa.contacts) {
                if(setresult.contains(cc.lastname)){ //Checks if set contains contact lastname.
                    conids.add(cc.id);
                }
                else{ //If not contains add lastname to set
                    setresult.add(cc.lastname);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The above code is working for records if we have duplicates more than only one. And its doesn't work for records if we have duplicates more than two 2 (like dup1,dup2,dup3,dup1,dup2,dup3,dup1,dup2 and dup3)

Comment: @KSKumaar I didn't get what do you mean by duplicates more than any number. If dup1 is a contact any contacts having last name as dup1 is a duplicate. So in that case the above code will work. In your question you need duplicate contact ids which will be there in `conIds`

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I Just small changes in what you suggested. Finally i got my requirement. Thank you @Reshma

Comment: @KSKumaar glad to help you.

Answer (score 1):

This query gets you a list ([aggregate](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm)) of lastNames of dupContacts for a given account Id

```
List<AggregateResult> aggrDupContacts=[select LastName from contact where AccountId=:accId group by LastName having count(Id)>1];
```

parse the `List<AggregateResult>` to a `List<String>`

Then you can get the list of dupContact ids with a simple SOQL query

```
List<Contact> dupContactIds=[select id from contact where lastName in :dupContactNames]
```

---

```
Public class Example11 {
    Public List<Contact> conts{set;get;}
    Public Set<String> setresult {set;get;}
    Public List<Id> conids {set;get;}

    Public void main(){
        setresult = new Set<String>();
        conIds = new List<Id>();
        conts = [select id,lastname,AccountId from Contact where Accountid='0012800001EcUSl' order by LastName];
        for(Contact cc: conts) {
             if(setresult.contains(cc.lastName)){
                 conids.add(cc.id); 
             }

             setresult.add(cc.lastname);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try this and let you know.

Comment: As i expected this line `List<Id> dupContactIds [select id from contact where lastName in :dupContactNames]` again will return all ids including duplicates. 
Even i checked too for verification.

Comment: @KSKumaar Yeah, I see, but when you have 2 contacts with LastName=`DUP` you can't tell if the dup is the first or the second one,  to achieve that you need to have a criteria that tell you which is the dup and which is not, otherwise you have to do that randomly in Apex

Comment: Yeah @benahm, i am trying it in multiple ways. Reshma answer working in one conditions and have to modify it.

Comment: @KSKumaar try the code above, I followed your code...

Answer (score 1):

Try this here you get last name wise duplicate ids.

```
Map<String,set<id>> contMap = new Map<String,set<id>>();
for(contact c:[select id,lastname,AccountId from Contact where AccountId = '0012800001EcUSl']) {
    if(contMap.containsKey(c.lastName)){
        contmap.get(c.lastname).add(c.id);
    } else
        contMap.put(c.lastName, new Set<id>{c.id}); 
}
System.debug(contMap);
for(string key:contMap.keySet())
   if(contMap.get(key).size() == 1)
       contMap.remove(key);
System.debug(contMap);
```